# Google Apps Script getBlob(): impossible to download the PDF file from URL

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf

I'm trying to use getBlob() to download PDF files from URLs on a website (e.g.: https://www.servizipubblicaamministrazione.it/servizi/saturnweb/DettaglioFile.aspx?Documento=9107-4933-brgvrcll1014):

```
function scraper(y){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//get the spreadsheet
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(y);//get the right sheet
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      if(data[i][2] != 0 && data[i][4] == 'da fare') { 
        var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(data[i][2]); 
        var type = blob.getBlob().getContentType();
        console.log(type);
        if(type == "application/pdf"){
          var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf"); 
        }else if(type == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"){
          var pdf = blob.getAs("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        }else if(type == "application/msword"){
          var pdf = blob.getAs("application/msword");
        }else if(type == "application/pkcs7-mime"){
          var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pkcs7-mime");
        }
        var attach = DriveApp.createFile(pdf).setName(data[i][9]); //i file cancellati tornano nella cartella root!!!
        var html = "<h1>Albo Pretorio Borgo Vercelli</h1>" +
             "<p>Nuovi documenti pubblicati sull'Albo Pretorio comunale: " +
             "- Titolo: " + data[i][3]
             "In allegato copia dei files pubblicati.<br />" +
             "Ciao!</p>";
        MailApp.sendEmail("xxx@gmail.com", data[i][9], "", { htmlBody: html, attachments: attach });
        DriveApp.getFilesByName(data[i][9]).next().setTrashed(true);
        ss.getSheetByName('raccolta').getRange(y+2, 8).setValue("inviato"); 
        var num = ss.getSheetByName('raccolta').getRange(y+2, 9).getValue(); 
        var tot = count();
        ss.getSheetByName('numero').getRange(tot+1, 1).setValue(num); 
      }
    }
}
```

The issue: the file I got via getBlob() it is a html page, not the PDF file. If I try to open the URL through Chrome, the PDF is showed in a PDFViewer.aspx page. If I try to open the URL through Android device I can download the PDF file. Can I change my code to reach the PDF file using getBlob()?

Comment: That page seems to actually be a pdf viewer, not the actual pdf. An they have countermeasures in place to prevent scarping. You would need the original pdf address to download it